# Equilateral Triangle within Equilateral triangle

Tags: algebra-precalculus, geometry, trigonometry

Determine the area of the equilateral triangle PQR using law of cosines.
[image]

Comment: Do you know angle A is $60^\circ$?  Use the law of cosines to find $CD$ to start.  Where are you stuck?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way:

1) From law of cosine find $AE$, then the angle $AEB$.

2) From law of sine find $AP$ and $QE$.

3) Find $PQ$.

Answer (score 1):

Let's observe that:

$$S_{PQR}=S_{ABC}-3S_{ABE}+3S_{ADP}$$

with

$$S_{ABC}=\frac12 \cdot 3\cdot3 \cdot \sin(60°) =\frac{9\sqrt3}{4}$$

$$S_{ABE}=\frac13 \cdot S_{ABC}=\frac{3\sqrt3}{4}$$

$$S_{ADP}=\frac19 \cdot S_{ABE}=\frac{1}{27} \cdot S_{ABC}=\frac{\sqrt3}{12}$$

thus

$$S_{PQR}=S_{ABC}-3S_{ABE}+3S_{ADP}=3S_{ADP}=\frac{\sqrt3}{4}$$